# Using replace method to replace numbers

Tags: c#, numbers, str-replace

I want to replace numbers like this:

```
Replace("55","a");
Replace("555","b");
```

I have the number `555` and want replace it with the letter `b` but when I run the code the program replaces `55` to `a` so the output would be like this: `a5`

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: reverse it. replace `555` first then `55`.

Comment: "How can i solve this problem??" - with just a little thought!  :)

Comment: Replace first 555, and then replace 55

Answer (score 3):

You can just flip the `Replace` calls around, like this:

```
var result = 
    input.Replace("555", "b")
         .Replace("55", "a");
```

This will first replace any `555`'s with a `b`, and only later, replace any remaining `55`'s with `a`.